# Unpack error occuring when sampling raster values to points with rasterio

Tags: python, raster, rasterio, fiona, sampling

I'm new to Python. I'm trying to sample raster values to points based on the geometries of a shapefile using the below code but I'm receiving the below error .

```
import fiona
import rasterio as rio
import pandas as pd

 multi_values_points = pd.Series()
 with fiona.open(inputShape) as shp:
     for feature in shp:
        Name = feature['properties']['Name']
        coords = feature['geometry']['coordinates']
        with rio.open(inputRaster) as stack_src:
           value = [v for v in stack_src.sample([coords])]
        multi_values_points.loc[Name] = value
 
 **ValueError: not enough values to unpack (expected 2, got 1)**
```

Comment: Hey, welcome to GIS SE. What line of your code is yielding your error? Furthermore, how many bands does your raster have?

Comment: The error has occured at value = [v for v in stack_src.sample([coords])] , my raster has 7 bands

Comment: Can you share a small portion of your data to do some tests?

Comment: can CRS of my shapefile cause this issue? I'm using WGS84 reference system

Comment: Do the points and the raster have the same CRS? If they do, it should not matter what the CRS is.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have figured out that coodinates of my raster data are in 3-Dimension and hence converted them to 2D as I no longer needed my z coordinate.